# Grails- How to limit each

Tags: grails, each

I have to present pictures from a list I have. I have to display only the 10 last pictures.

```
<div class="ad-thumbs">
                <ul class="bxslider">
                    <pictures:each bean="${bean}">
                        <g:if test="${picture}">
                            <g:if test = "${picture.getLargeImageURL() != null && picture.getThumbnailImageURL() != null}">
                                <li>
                                        <img src="${picture.getLargeImageURL()}" style="height: 240px; width: 100%"  alt="${picture.copyright.copyrightify()}" title="${picture.caption.linkify()}"/>
                                </li>
                            </g:if>
                            <g:elseif test="${largeFileName != null && thumbnailFileName != null }">
                                <li>
                                        <img src="${resource(dir:'imgService',file:largeFileName)}" style="height: 240px; width: 100%" alt="${picture.copyright.copyrightify()}" title="${picture.caption.linkify()}"/>
                                </li>
                            </g:elseif>
                        </g:if>
                    </pictures:each>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: how do you get the `pictureList`?

Comment: I send it from another file.

Comment: post the code. in general you should do all list transformation in a controller or service

Comment: domainclass?.findAllById(params.id, [sort: "lastUpdated", order:"DESC", offset:"0", max:"10"] )